# Can you use LaTex in RCloud?

Tags: r, latex, rcloud

I want to write the equations like the logistic function in the narrative of my analysis in my RCloud notebook using LaTex (because that is what I know), for example:

```
F(x) = 1/(1 + exp(-Ax))

g(F(x)) = ln(\frac{F(x)}{1-F(x)}) = Ax

\frac{F(x)}{1-F(x)} = e^{Ax}
```

Can I use LaTeX notation in RCloud?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, in an **RMarkdown cell** in an RCloud (showcase instance at rcloud.social/tryit) notebook this will render:

```
### If $x$ is a linear function then the argument to the logistic function can be written as a linear system.

$$
F(x) = 1/(1 + exp(-Ax))
$$

### $F(x)$ can be interpretted as the probability of the independent variable $x$ producing an output of 1 given the design matrix $A$.

### When training a binomial logistic regression model we are interested in the inverse problem.  That is, given a set of examples what is the optimal value of $A$.

$$
g(F(x)) = ln(\frac{F(x)}{1-F(x)}) = Ax
$$
$$
\frac{F(x)}{1-F(x)} = e^{Ax}
$$

### Note that the $g$, called the *logit* function, is equivalent to simple linear regression and
```

is also the log odds of F(x).

[This](https://rcloud.social/view.html?notebook=bf599ab697ac92754cedcdcc8d14952f) is an example notebook on the showcase/public instance of RCloud.